# show array index number ospecific ID

Tags: php, arrays

I have a  array.i am using php.

This is json array

```
{

    "score":[
        {
            "userId":"5",
            "playtime":"1396435708",
            "score":"234"
        },
        {
            "userId":"5",
            "playtime":"1396369254",
            "score":"25"
        },
        {
            "userId":"4",
            "playtime":"1396369056",
            "score":"12"
        },
        {
            "userId":"7",
            "playtime":"1396369246",
            "score":"2"
        },
        {
            "userId":"6",
            "playtime":"1396369240",
            "score":"1"
        }
    ],
    "MyPosition":"2"
}
```

here myposition shows only 2 for userId=5.

but It will be 1 and 2

I am currently using this code

```
foreach($leadBoard as $key=>$value) {
    if($value['user_id'] == $userId) {

        $myposition=$key+1;
    }
}
```

How can i show all position

Comment: You'd need to use an array (`$myposition = array();`) to hold the positions, not just a single variable.  `$myposition[] = $key+1;`

Comment: It is not too clear what exactly you are asking... Could you please add the desired output so that we can see the example?

Comment: "MyPosition": [
        "",
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
there show a "" item using your code @RocketHazmat

Comment: @user3490043: It works for me: https://eval.in/130732 (Note your JSON has `userId`, but your `foreach` has `user_id`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have many position, I would recommend using an array.

```
 $myposition = array();
 foreach($leadBoard as $key=>$value) {
      if($value['user_id'] == $userId) {
           array_push($myposition,$key);
      }
 }
```

After, you can loop on this position array or implode it to a single string, depending on what action you want to use it for.